# Drawing a chart

Tags: javascript, c#, inheritance

I would like to draw a chart using this code

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "addClassNames": true,
        "theme": "light",
        "pathToImages": "/lib/3/images/",
        "autoMargins": false,
        "marginLeft": 30,
        "marginRight": 8,
        "marginTop": 10,
        "marginBottom": 26,
        "dataProvider": [
            {
                "maand": @Model.Maanden[0],
                "neerslag": 33,
                "temperatuur": 33
            },
            {
                "maand": "Februari",
                "neerslag": 33,
                "temperatuur": 33
            }
        ],
        "valueAxes": [
            {
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "position": "left"
            }
        ],
        "startDuration": 1,
        "graphs": [
            {
                "alphaField": "alpha",
                "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:13px;'>[[title]] in [[category]]:<b>[[value]]</b> [[additional]]</span>",
                "dashLengthField": "dashLengthColumn",
                "fillAlphas": 1,
                "title": "Gemiddelde neerslag",
                "type": "column",
                "valueField": "neerslag"
            }, {
                "id": "graph2",
                "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:13px;'>[[title]] in [[category]]:<b>[[value]]</b> [[additional]]</span>",
                "bullet": "round",
                "lineThickness": 3,
                "bulletSize": 7,
                "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
                "bulletBorderThickness": 3,
                "fillAlphas": 0,
                "lineAlpha": 1,
                "title": "Gemiddelde temperatuur",
                "valueField": "temperatuur"
            }
        ],
        "categoryField": "maand",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "gridPosition": "start",
            "axisAlpha": 0,
            "tickLength": 0
        }
    });



</script>
```

when I use "maand": @Model.Maanden[0] instead of a string it doesn't draw a chart but I know I can access the properties in the model what am I  doing wrong?

Comment: try use: `"maand": '@Model.Maanden[0]'`

Comment: That worked but why do you need to place te ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `"maand": '@Model.Maanden[0]'` because if you dont put the `''` the javascript will understand that the value of the `"maand"` is `@Model.Maanden[0]` and not the value of `@Model.Maanden[0]`.

Comment: i did that and it worked but now I would like to put floats in the "neerslag" using `'@Model.Neerslagen[0]'` but he doesn't want to show the numbers I even made a list to make doubles of it but it also didn't work

Comment: try uset it: `parseFloat('@Model.Neerslagen[0]')`